# Android 2.2 - WebView, how to open the website with <video> tag inside?

Tags: android, video, webview

How to open the webside like:

```
<html><body style="background-color: rgb(38,38,38);"><video controls="" autoplay="" style="margin: auto; position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;" name="media" src="http://##########################.mp4"></video></body></html>
```

in webview. Not even inside the webview, but can be on new intent.
Thanks very much for any help.
Regards

Comment: I added http://code.google.com/p/html5webview/ class, but it didn't help. Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, I created override for loading to force to open a video activity and pass the link directly to the file:

```
@Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
                {
                    if (url.endsWith(".mp4") )
                    {                           
                        data.url = url;
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VideoPlayer.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        return true;
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
                    }
                }
```